# Issue with commiting new files in Sourcetree

Tags: gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I am just starting with Sourcetree,
In the past few days during coding, I was implementing new changes, and committing, It's all fine so far.

However, I noticed some of these changes were unnecessary, so I tried to reset to the point before these implementations were done. I did the following:

• On the commit ***Header file with CC01...*** I have right-clicked and choose ***Reset current branch to this commit.***

Then. from this point I added new implementations, source and harder files. But after committing and pushing I noticed no change was forwarded to the Gitlab.

I was wondering if it was related to the Reset that I have performed, so on the upper red ***init commit*** I chose the option to merge, but this was deleting all the changes and files that were correct.

So, I would like to know how can I solve this and keep my files. Preferably deleting these changes that are stated on the right side in red.

Below is the image of the commits to illustrate this issue:

[image]

The right-click options:

[image]